# How can I combine two COUNT() statements into one and get the difference?

Tags: mysql

How can I combine the following two queries into one to get `result` as the difference of the two counts. Or where result is:

`result = vote1 - vote2`

```
SELECT COUNT(id) AS vote1 FROM votes WHERE votes.voteTypeId = @voteType1 AND votes.userId = @userId
SELECT COUNT(id) AS vote2 FROM votes WHERE votes.voteTypeId = @voteType2 AND votes.userId = @userId
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT  SUM(votetypeid = @votetype1) - SUM(votetypeid = @votetype2)
FROM    votes
WHERE   userid = @userid
        AND votetypeid IN (@votetype1, @votetype2)
```

Comment: Slick.  I do like me a nice exploit of the intersection between Boolean logic and integer arithmetic.

Comment: this is very cool. I had no idea you could do that. Could you be kind enough to comment on the difference between your approach and that of the second answer in the context of why to use one and not the other? Thanks!

Comment: @Mel: Joe's answer will read all user's records, not only those with these two vote types. If you add `AND votetypeid IN (@votetype1, @votetype2)` into his query, it will be the same as mine, with the same performance. Scalar calculations are very fast in `MySQL` and it does not really matter whether you use `CASE` or boolean arithmetic, compared to the time to retrieve the records.

Answer (score 1):

```
select sum(case when voteTypeId = @voteType1 then 1
                when voteTypeId = @voteType2 then -1
                else 0
           end) as result
    from votes
    where userId = @userId
```